# T-SQL Replace part of a not null column with NULL generates error

Tags: t-sql, replace, null, notnull

I have table variable and all its columns can not be null (NOT NULL definition for each):

```
DECLARE @SampleTable 
(
   ,SampleColumnID nvarchar(400) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
   ,SampleColumnText nvarchar(max) NOT NULL
)
```

I have done some operation with this variable and initialize the "SampleColumnText" with some text.

Then I try to replace some part of it with text return from other function. What happens is that the function returns NULL in some cases, so I this code generates me error:

```
REPLACE(SampleColumnText , '{*}', @InitByFunctionText)
```

WHERE @InitByFunctionText is NULL this time.

So, is it normal error to be generated as I am replacing only part of the text with NULL, not the whole text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. [`REPLACE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx):

> Returns `NULL` if any one of the arguments is `NULL`.

If you want to replace it with an empty string (which is *not* the same as `NULL`), you can use [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx):

```
REPLACE(SampleColumnText , '{*}', COALESCE(@InitByFunctionText,''))
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar thing recently and the following got around this issue:

```
REPLACE(SampleColumnText , '{*}', ISNULL(@InitByFunctionText, ''))
```